# How does one export camelcase class names in a python package?

Tags: python-3.x, package

I am creating a python package, it has a file called `testclass`. In it, I have

```
class TestClass:
     def __init__(self)
         print ("hello world")
```

I have a setup.py file, very barebone with only the required fields.

To build this package, I run `python3 - build`

I install this package from a git repo `pip install git+https://github.com/...`
The package name is mypackage.
In a test file I write

```
from mypackage import testclass
a = TestClass()
```

I get the error

```
NameError: name 'TestClass' is not defined
```

to work around the error, I have say `testclass.TestClass`.
Is there a way to simply say

```
a = TestClass()
```

I see a lot of standard packages that are installed on my machine that come with a package directory and a *-1.1.1.dist-info directory. Using those packages on does not need to mention the filename before using the exported class such as `a = TestClass()`

Where does the content of `this` directory come from and can be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from mypackage.testclass import TestClass`.

Alternatively you may create a `__init__.py` file under `mypackage` with the following code:

```
from .testclass import TestClass
```

You may then use

```
from mypackage import TestClass
```

Comment: when I add the mentioned line in __init__.py, I get an error : TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'region_name'

Comment: @reza That is an unrelated error stemming from testclass.py

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my oversight. Adding the recommend entry in __init__ file does not see to change anything. In the file that I use the class, I still have to say from mypackage.testclass import TestClass

Comment: What's the new directory tree after adding it?

Comment: I already has a __init__.py under my package name directory. I just added the line.
src/mypackage/__init__.py and my testclass.py is in the same directory.

Comment: Try `from .testclass import TestClass` maybe. I'm not entire sure why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yes, that last one worked @Bharel. If you want to answer the question to get the credit, go for it

Comment: @reza I'm not entirely sure what do you mean. Are you trying to use it without an import at all?

Comment: what I am trying to say is that recommended solution is accurate and solved my problem.

Comment: @reza Awesome, glad I could help, you're welcome to mark as accepted. I've modified the answer accordingly. Keep in mind the previous solution should have worked as well, not sure why it didn't. It's exactly the same.